# How to store a reference to another element on a jquery parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm constructing some DOM elements on the page and want to keep a reference to a child element on the parent for updates later

```
    for(i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
            const item = $(`<div></div>`);
            item.addClass('List_Item');

            item.title = $(`<div></div>`).addClass('List_Title');
            item.append(item.title);

            $(item).init.prototype.getName = function() {
              return $(this).data('name');
            }
            
            $(item).init.prototype.setName = function(name) {
              $(this).data('name', name);
              $(this).find('.List_Title').text(name);
            }
            
            item.setName(sources[i].name);
    }
```

How can I avoid using `.find()` in this manner to grab the child element with a selector and instead keep a reference to it on the `item` element itself?

**Edit:**

I've opted for a function saved to a .data() store

```
            item.data('name', sources[i].name);
            
            var getName = function() {
              return item.data('name');
            }

            var setName = function(name) {
              item.data('name', name);
              title.text(name);
            }
            item.data('setName', setName);
```

I can then access this externally later like so

```
          $('.List_Item').each(function(index, item) {
            if($(item).data('name') == prevName) {
              var setName = $(item).data('setName');
              setName(newName);
            }
          });
```

Comment: 1) why would you not want to use `find()`? That's what it's (and the DOM) is for 2) Why are you prototyping methods off a jQuery object? That's really not good practice. It may be better if you could tell us exactly what you're trying to achieve, as I'm certain there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm pulling data from an API and creating elements for each entry. When a rename event comes in, I want to find the entry based on data attribute on the parent, and programmatically find the title child element to update it's text.

Searching with a selector feels hacky to me as opposed to having a proper reference?

Comment: Could you not just create a named reference directly on the DOM element that the jQuery object is wrapping? `item.myReference = otherDomElement`